# WPF browser loadCompleted/Navigated not firing on SOME machines

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a pretty simple wpf application. Works great on my machine. But when I install it on another machine, the browser's loadCompleted event does not fire. Based on other similar questions & answers, I have tried:
- use navigated event instead of loadCompleted - does not fire either
- use windows form browser instead of wpf browser - does not fire
- ensure app is fully loaded before navigating: tried putting the navigate call in the window's Loaded event, even threw in a 5 second sleep for good luck - does not fire

Like I said, works like a charm on my machine, both from within Visual Studio and when I execute it from the command line.

So I'm thinking it's something about the other machine. Any ideas what environmental factors would prevent the loadComplete/Navigated events from firing?

Thanks!

[edited: just tried it on another co-worker's machine, and the loadCOmpleted event does not fire there either. So it seems to just fire the event on my machine/the machine it is built on. Not sure if that gives anyone a clue to this frustrating little mystery...)

Answer (score 0):

OK, well this is mildly embarrassing. The events were indeed firing, but my messagebox messages were not showing up. Before it could get to that step, the app encountered a fatal error. There were two problems that worked together to cause me days of untold angst:

1) I had deployed the debug version of my app to the two remote machines. Neither of those machines were developer machines, and they did not have the debug version of the redistributable Visual Studio gunk. So it was failing trying to load one of my dlls, because of the dependency on the debug libraries.

2) Poor error handling failed to catch this error, so it just looked like the event was not firing.

Lesson learned: make sure you have proper try/catches !!